# Expresiones regulares en MySQL que acepten "Ñ"

Tags: mysql, regex

Tengo un problema con mi procedimiento almacenado que es una expresión regular que solo acepta letras pero no me aceptan **`Ñ`** en mayúsculas en MySQL.

Estoy intentando con:

```sql
columna regexp '^[a-z]+$'
```

pero no coincide con un valor como `abcñ`

Esta es mi tabla de prueba:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tabla
    (`columna` varchar(7))
; 

INSERT INTO Tabla
    (`columna`)
VALUES
    ('abcd'),
    ('abcñ'),
    ('ABCD'),
    ('ABCÑ')
;
```

Comment: Hola Luis. Bienvenido a StackOverflow Español. Te sugiero tomar el tiempo de repasar los enlaces [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) para poder mejorar la pregunta. En este momento, no has incluído suficiente información para poder ayudarte. Cómo mínimo, debes incluír el código de tu procedimiento.

Comment: @LuisSantiago modifiqué tu pregunta para que contenga la información necesaria en una pregunta del sitio. Si hay algo incorrecto, no dudes en comentarlo y/o [edit] para que se ajuste a lo que estás preguntando

Answer (score 2):

### Opción 1. Agregar Ñ a la clase de caracteres.

Dentro de la [clase de caracteres](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) se puede agregar cualquier caracter que desees permitir que coincida:

```sql
select columna
  from Tabla
 where columna regexp '^[A-Za-zÑñ]+$';
```

### Opción 2. Coincidir con `alpha`

Dentro de la clase de caracteres, se puede utlizar la [clase POSIX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) **`alpha`**, que coincide con `ñ` y muchos otros diacríticos, como tildes, diéresis, etc. De esta forma, la expresión regular coincide con caracteres alfabéticos, aunque también acepta muchos otros caracteres de distintos idiomas.

```sql
select columna
  from Tabla
 where columna regexp '^[[:alpha:]]+$';
```

---

#### Pruebas

Ejemplo para probar ambas expresiones:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tabla (`columna` varchar(7));

INSERT INTO Tabla (`columna`)
VALUES ('abcd'), ('abcñ'), ('ABCD'), ('ABCÑ'), ('ábcdé'),
       ('ÁBCDÉ'), ('áòçñüïô'), ('AB DE'), ('123abcd');

select
       columna,
       case when columna regexp '^[A-Za-zÑñ]+$' then 'Sí' else 'No' end as '^[A-Za-zÑñ]+$',
       case when columna regexp '^[[:alpha:]]+$' then 'Sí' else 'No' end as '^[[:alpha:]]+$'
  from Tabla;
```

**Resultado:**

```sql
       columna   ^[A-Za-zÑñ]+$   ^[[:alpha:]]+$  
 ---- --------- --------------- ---------------- 
   1   abcd      Sí              Sí              
   2   abcñ      Sí              Sí              
   3   ABCD      Sí              Sí              
   4   ABCÑ      Sí              Sí              
   5   ábcdé     No              Sí              
   6   ÁBCDÉ     No              Sí              
   7   áòçñüïô   No              Sí              
   8   AB DE     No              No              
   9   123abcd   No              No
```

[<kbd>Demo en rextester.com</kbd>](http://rextester.com/NTU31828)